# If twig replace isnt called, replace by nothing

Tags: twig

I want to give my users control over an input field via twig replace. So I created a var

```
<input type='text' %attr%>
```

Now with twig:

```
{{ var | replace({"%attr%":"id='12'"}) | raw}}
```

But if my users dont use replace, I dont want to display %attr% in the input field.
Is there a native twig way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean? `if my users dont use replace`?

Comment: They are the creators of the template. I only provide the variables. If they dont replace %attrs% there is an ugly %attrs% in my code...

Comment: Could you clarify: `I only provide the variable`? You mean you provide the HTML with that placeholder `%attr%`?

Comment: Yes, I manage the controller, someone else manages the view. I pass a variable containing  `<input type='text' %attr%>` and then it's up to the designer to use twig in the view. But I don't want %attr% to be present, when he forgets to replace it.

Comment: to be honest, this is bad design, you shouldn't be responsible to send HTML to the designer. Guess it's better to rethink your strategy

Answer (score 0):

As already commented, this is a bad design and it would be better to rethink your strategy. Anyhow a possible solution would be to write a custom filter and use that one over the `raw` filter.

By adding the option `is_safe` to the filter, the filter will behave exactly like `raw`, but you have more control over the end result.

In this case, you could replace `%attr%` if it hasn't been replaced by the filter `replace` before. You could even extend this list if needed be

```
$twig->addFilter(new \Twig\TwigFilter('safe', function($val) {
    return str_replace([
        '%attr%',
    ],[
        '',
    ], $val);
}, ['is_safe' => ['html']]);
```

After you've added the filter to twig, you can use this filter anywhere:

```
{{ var | replace({"%attr%":"id='12'"}) | safe }}
{{ var | safe }}
```